# confused using Jquery in Asp.net (User control)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Currently I am working in a page that has 3 usercontrols. I need put a loading image when I search in one User control I used the code below:

The div in HTML:

```
<div class="loading">
    <img src="../images/Loading/466.gif" title="Cargando" alt="Cargando" class="Load" />
</div>
```

the Jquery (I found It in google, before I saw a lot of examples, I don't know If is good use `setTimeout` for this)

```
function ShowProgress() {
var table = $("#Table");
table.css("opacity", ".2");

   setTimeout(function () {
        var modal = $('<div />');
        modal.addClass("modal");
        $('table').append(modal);
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.show();
        var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
        var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
        loading.css({ top: top, left: left }
        );
    });
}
```

And my ASP button (It is inside the User control):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" SkinID="botonEstandar" Text="Buscar" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"
                                                     ValidationGroup="BasicFilter" OnClientClick="return ShowProgress();"
                                                    meta:resourcekey="btnSearchResource1" />
```

**My Problem**

It is when I made a search the div modal show the loading image, but How I block all controls of the user controls at the page?.

I really don't know If is good show the loading .

I'm sorry If I did anything bad but I'm starting with Jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out the [Block UI Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f4es/2/) on how it works

So all you have to do is add a reference to the block ui script in your code. On click of your search button just call:

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<div class="loading"><img src="../images/Loading/466.gif" title="Cargando" alt="Cargando" class="Load" /></div>' });
```

The above code will block all functions on your screen and show your custom message(which in this case is the html that you passed to the plugin)

After your search returns a result you should do:

```
$.unblockUI();
```

This will remove the loading image and the user can again interact with your page.

Comment: I think this is the best way to accomplish my requirement. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
A simple method is there..
on the OnClientclick of your button , hide the main div or panel(which is having your all controls)  using JQuery and just show your div with the loading image. If a post back is happening there, then it is the simple and easy method.
```

please see the below aspx page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProgress() {
            $('#divWithAllControls').hide();
            $('.loading').show();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="divWithAllControls">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" SkinID="botonEstandar" Text="Buscar" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"
            ValidationGroup="BasicFilter" OnClientClick="return ShowProgress();" meta:resourcekey="btnSearchResource1" />
    </div>
    <div class="loading">
        <img src="../images/Loading/466.gif" title="Cargando" alt="Cargando" class="Load" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```